# Change style component when validation error occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I need to change a field style when a validator finds an error. In my view I've done that

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Editar")" method="post" name="fCadastro" id="fCadastro" class="stdform" role="form">
    <p>
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <span class="field field-validation-error">
            <input type="text" name="Nome" id="nome" class="form-control" value="@Model.Nome" maxlength="50" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
         </span>
         <small class="desc">Informe o nome do produto. Tamanho máximo: 50 caracateres</small>
    </p>
</form>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.additional.methods.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" defer></script>
}
```

My ViewModel class has:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

I have configured web.config with:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

So, I need to apply an error style and set focus to the field with error, not only show the error message. One of solutions I already have tried is to override the errorPlacement funtion of Unobtrusive:

```
settings.errorPlacement = function (label, element) {
    // Call old handler so it can update the HTML
    oldErrorPlacement(label, element);

    form.addClass('has-error');
    element.parents('span').addClass('text-danger');
    element.focus();
};
```

but without success.

Comment: But using it you only change the style of the error message